# How to click check box with Python Selenium when ID changes each time the page loads?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a checkbox that is within a div.   However, the ID changes each time the page loads so I can't use the ID, but I need to click the checkbox based on other data in the div.  The check box I am trying to select is the last one in the example below and has this account code associated with it, 531377222.

I may be able to use XPATH, but I am not sure how to associate the account code I need with the appropriate check box.

Here is the html for the check boxes.

```
 <div class="slick-pane slick-pane-header slick-pane-right" tabindex="0" style="display: none;">
                           <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:150px">
                                    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"><input id="selector9588897" type="checkbox"><label for="selector9588897"></label></div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">173622856</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">SOME HOSPITAL</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">1234 Main St., Anywhere, CA                                                                           US</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 reallyHidden">Both</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:200px">
                                    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"><input id="selector1002169" type="checkbox"><label for="selector1002169"></label></div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">184054655</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">SOME HOSPITAL/ACCTS</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">5555 ELM AVE, ANYWHERE, NJ 64545-1621                                                                           US</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 reallyHidden">Both</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:250px">
                                    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"><input id="selector751814" type="checkbox"><label for="selector751814"></label></div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">265215254</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">SOME ENTITIY</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">321 MAIN ST STE 310, ANYWHERE, CA 56456-1757                                                                           US</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 reallyHidden">Both</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:300px">
                                    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"><input id="selector374087" type="checkbox"><label for="selector374087"></label></div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">267106207</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">SOME ENTITY</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">321 MAIN ST STE 310, ANYWHERE, CA 56456-1757                                                                           US</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 reallyHidden">Both</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:350px">
                                    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"><input id="selector3010516" type="checkbox"><label for="selector3010516"></label></div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">305663190</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">ANOTHER ENTITY</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">147 E BROADWAY, SOMETOWN, MN 67777-5844                                                                              US</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 reallyHidden">Both</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:450px">
                                    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"><input id="selector7278518" type="checkbox"><label for="selector7278518"></label></div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">667508371</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">AAA OUTBOUND</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">134 MAIN STREET STE 310, SOME CITY, CA 98745-1757                                                                           US</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 reallyHidden">Both</div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:500px">
                                    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"><input id="selector3764758" type="checkbox"><label for="selector3764758"></label></div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">687324935</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">BBB OUTBOUND</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">5645 POPPYSEED DRIVE STE 310, SOME CITY, CA 65456-1757                                                                           US</div>        
                                   <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 reallyHidden">Both</div>
                                 </div>                       
                                    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-checkboxsel"><input id="selector5842832" type="checkbox" checked="checked"><label for="selector5842832"></label></div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">531377222</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2">N/A</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">N/A</div>
                                    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 reallyHidden">Both</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following `xpath` to identify checkbox element based on associate code.

```
//div[text()='531377222']/preceding-sibling::div[1]//label
```

or

```
//div[text()='531377222']/preceding-sibling::div[1]//input
```

---

If you want to make this dynamic use python format() function and pass associate code as an argument.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus : if you check the html `input` element is not the actual sibling of `div` element you have referred to. It is the child of another `div` element which is sibling of associate code `div` element. By the way we both posted at the same time, I haven't seen your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should solve your issue (if I understood your question):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

browser.get(url)
##[...] your code
account_id = '1234567'
corresponding_checkbox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'div[text()= "{account_id}"]/preceding-sibling::div/input)))'
```